# Is the sending of data to moodle REST API limited?

Tags: php, rest, moodle, moodle-api

I'm using moodle 3.5, I'm trying to send an array of 2308 (user/corresponding cohort) to the external function 'core_cohort_add_cohort_members' by POST, the answer of the API is :

```
array(3) {
  ["exception"]=>
  string(27) "invalid_parameter_exception"
  ["errorcode"]=>
  string(16) "invalidparameter"
  ["message"]=>
  string(42) "Valeur incorrecte de paramètre détectée"
}
```

But when I'm sending this array by chunk (250 lines by 250 lines) it's working. So I was wondering, is there any limit from Moodle? Can we change this limit ? Is this limit coming from a limitation of max_file_upload on PHP settings (mine is 256MB) ?

Documentation of Moodle is not specific about that...

Thanks for your answer !

Comment: You can have more informations about the error if you turn on the debugger mode and allow the debbuging messages to be displayed.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at that when I will be back on this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be `max-input-vars` ? The default is 1000 variables.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars

You will need to increase the value in `php.ini`